# Do I Need to COMMIT a read Tx if I dont use WITH UR in DB2

Tags: transactions, db2, locking

I am using DB2 as my backend. I have a couple of select queries (with inner join and order by clause). In both scenarios I am not using "WITH UR" clause.

Now the problem I face is after using the same queries in prod for a significant period of time I start getting this error:

> UNSUCCESSFUL EXECUTION CAUSED BY AN UNAVAILABLE RESOURCE. REASON 00C90096, TYPE OF RESOURCE 00000302, AND RESOURCE NAME DPGDS0  .SPGDS04 .X'0186B4'. SQLCODE=-904, SQLSTATE=57011, DRIVER=3.69.24

Is it anything to do with the way I wrote the select queries. Here is the query for your reference:

```
SELECT 
  A.NOTF_MSG_REF_I, A.NOTF_MSG_I, A.NOTF_MSG_TYPE_C,A.FROM_GLN_I, A.TO_GLN_I, A.MKT_CTRY_C,
  A.VEND_GLN_I,A.UCCNET_MSG_I,B.ITEM_PRPSL_I , B.NOTF_GTIN_PKG_T, c.prod_req_stat_c 
FROM db2prod.NOTF_MSG A 
INNER JOIN ( 
  db2prod.i_prod_req C 
  INNER JOIN 
    db2prod.i_PROD_REQ_SRC_MAP D 
    INNER JOIN 
    db2prod.ITEM_NOTF_GMS_S B 
    ON D.PROD_REQ_SRC_MAP_I= B.ITEM_PRPSL_I 
  ON C.prod_req_i= D.prod_req_i ) 
ON  A.NOTF_MSG_REF_I = B.NOTF_MSG_REF_I 
WHERE A.NOTF_MSG_TYPE_C IN (
 'INITIAL_LOAD', 'INITIALLOAD','CHANGE', 'DATA_CHANGE','CORRECTION',
 'NEW_ITEM','NEW','MODIFY') 
AND A.CNFM_RESP_C = 'PENDING' 
ORDER BY A.NOTF_MSG_REF_I, B.ITEM_PRPSL_I DESC
```

The DBA is saying I am hitting the maximum locks and I need to take commits.

Do I need to commit the read transaction explicitly?

I tried restarting the app server, but that didn't help.

Comment: You do need to commit _any_ transaction to release the locks, but that is not going to help you because you can't commit until your query finishes anyway.

Comment: thanks mustaccio, do you suggest using WITH RC

Comment: I don't know what "WITH RC" is, but generally speaking you need to use the isolation level that is dictated by your business rules and the application logic.